# Promise implementation - Why is it necessary to store handler as an array?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm looking at the implementation of simple promise from https://www.promisejs.org/implementing/

I get most of the things here... but I'm not sure why this particular example needs to store handler as an array.

if we are pushing array only when the state is PENDING by the following code

```
function handle(handler) {
  if (state === PENDING) {
    handlers.push(handler);
  } else {
    if (state === FULFILLED &&
      typeof handler.onFulfilled === 'function') {
      handler.onFulfilled(value);
    }
    if (state === REJECTED &&
      typeof handler.onRejected === 'function') {
      handler.onRejected(value);
    }
  }
}
```

but then if we fulfill and change the state = !PENDING right away by the following before calling the state,

```
function fulfill(result) {
  state = FULFILLED;
  value = result;
  handlers.forEach(handle);
  handlers = null;
}

function reject(error) {
  state = REJECTED;
  value = error;
  handlers.forEach(handle);
  handlers = null;
}
```

even if the done is called asynchrounsly

```
this.done = function (onFulfilled, onRejected) {
  // ensure we are always asynchronous
  setTimeout(function () {
    handle({
      onFulfilled: onFulfilled,
      onRejected: onRejected
    });
  }, 0);
}
```

I don't see how handlers will have more than 1 element because whenever we process then, whether we process another process in it, we will always observe on new promise object.

i.e. Under what condition we will require to store multiple success & failure handler on the same promise?

I'm failing to see it.

Please help me understand.

Comment: you can invoke `.then` on a single promise as many times as you like - each time you do so, you need to add a handler if the promise is pending

Comment: by the way, you would never *actually* implement the calling of the handlers like `handlers.forEach(handle);`, for obvious reasons

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding what you meant. When you say invoke the then on a single promise as many times as you like, are you talking about the promise chain? meaning new Promise()....then(e => e).then(e=>e)... and such? The thing is every time we observe with then, it will create new instance of promise. And I believe fulfill or reject is only ensured to be called on this particular example on then. Only other thing that I can imagine is when you call the done function since this is exposed, which does not return new promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true that *Promise chains* do not add "additional handlers" to the head (first promise) of the chain.

In the case of a promise chain, each `.then` or `.catch` down the chain, returns a *new* Promise, therefore, you are correct that with Promise chains, you only need a single "handler"

However, any Promise can have more than one "listener" ... i.e. you can call its `.then` method multiple times ... the promise returned by `.then` is new, however, `p` is still the same promise, so any `.then` invoked on it is added as a handler

```js
const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'result'));

// this .then is handlers[0] on p
p.then(r => console.log(`promise resolved with [${r}]`));

// this .then is handlers[1] on p
p.then(r => console.log(`you can add more than one "listener" to a promise - the result here is [${r}]`));

// here is a promise chain, this too only adds one handler to the Promise "p"
p
// this .then is handlers[2] on p
.then(r => `a third handler [${r}]`) // this is added to handlers
.then(console.log); // but this .then is NOT a handler on p, 
      //it's a handler on the promise returned by the previous `.then`
```

Comment: Got it. I was trying to see how I will make handlers to have more than one element... Seems to work on async process (or delegated) when multiple then is working on the same promise object. Didn't even think about this edge case.

Comment: How is this an "edge" case?

Comment: No - edge case meaning on my local testing scenarios. I wasn't really thinking of the real world application. But now I think about the actual scenario, this was the whole point of asynchronous programming.